# Accessing element in Ember View

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a view setup that has a canvas and several inputs in it.
I am calling an action in the view when a button is pressed and I need to access the canvas and input's.
Obviously I could use something like what I have below but if I have more than 1 of these view's on a page then getting an element via ID just isn't going to cut it.

> var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasThumbResult");

I have the canvas setup like this in the view's template

```
<canvas id="canvasThumbResult" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
```

Is there a good way to get an element from an action in Ember or is there a way I can search for the element only inside the current view's output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access any HTML Element within your `Ember.View` with `this.$(/*jquery identifier*/)` so, for an example you can access your canvas like

```
var App.MyCanvasView = Ember.View.extend({
  actions: {
    myAction: function () {
      console.log(this.$('#canvasThumbResult'));
    }
  }
});
```